# Programmatically access Enterprise Library Logging configuration (object model)?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, enterprise-library

I'm using [Enterprise Library 3.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650466.aspx) and want to programmatically access the [Logging Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647183.aspx) (runtime, object model) specifically its Trace Listeners and Sources.

For example, I want to access the `Filename` property of a trace listener object so I can know where the log file is located on disk.

**Update:** Looking for answers that use the runtime object model, not by parsing the XML configuration.

Comment: A similar question was asked on CodePlex in 2007: http://entlib.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=16380

Comment: Is it acceptable to use the EL configuration object model to determine the properties?  Are you using programmatic configuration of EL without XML configuration?

Comment: @Tuzo: Thanks for asking. I am using XML configuration, and for you to use the EL configuration object model is acceptable. To clarify further what's not acceptable is side-stepping any EL object model, for example, pulling out a plain old XML parser and loading the config with it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the logging configuration programmatically using the object model (used for configuration).

To get the specific data for the trace listener you should look at [TraceListenerData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.logging.configuration.tracelistenerdata%28PandP.31%29.aspx) (and the specific subclasses).

This example shows how to read in the configuration and then get the TraceListeners:

```
// Open config file
ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"MyApp.exe.config";

Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

// Get EL log settings
LoggingSettings log = config.GetSection("loggingConfiguration") as LoggingSettings;

// Get TraceListener info
foreach(TraceListenerData listener in log.TraceListeners)
{
    // Check for listener types you care about
    if (listener is RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData)
    {
        RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData data = listener as RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Found RollingFlatFileLIstener with Name={0}, FileName={1}, Header={2}, Footer={3}, RollSizeKB={4}, TimeStampPattern={5},RollFileExistsBehavior={6}, RollInterval={7}, TraceOutputOptions={8}, Formatter={9}, Filter={10}",
            data.Name, data.FileName, data.Header, data.Footer, data.RollSizeKB, 
            data.TimeStampPattern, data.RollFileExistsBehavior, data.RollInterval,
            data.TraceOutputOptions, data.Formatter, data.Filter);
    }
    else // other trace listener types e.g. FlatFileTraceListenerData 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this much better than my runtime/reflection attempt. Thanks.

Comment: Note: Works in **4.1** _versión_ , not for ***5.0*** **Not compiles** `LoggingSettings log = config.GetSection("loggingConfiguration") as LoggingSettings;`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently some needed info is privately encapsulated in a `LogWriterStructureHolder` instance (its field is named *structureHolder*) on the Enterprise Library **Logger.Writer** instance (of Type `LogWriter`).
So I'm effectively looking for: `Logger.Writer.structureHolder` (but that field is private).

I used reflection to pull it out....

These are the significant namespaces:

```
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging;
```

This is reflection code to pull out the needed private data:

```
// Get the private field.
FieldInfo fiLogStructHolder 
    = typeof(LogWriter).GetField("structureHolder", BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

// Obtain field value to get the private data.
LogWriterStructureHolder structureHolder 
    = (LogWriterStructureHolder)fiLogStructHolder.GetValue(Logger.Writer);

// Access the value's .TraceSources property of Type Dictionary<string, LogSource>.
// The string is the name of the category from configuration. 
int numSources = structureHolder.TraceSources.Count;

// Furthermore, access the listeners of any logging source by specifying:
int numListeners = structureHolder.TraceSources[0].Listeners.Count
                                             // ^-- Note: Picked first source for example.
```

**If anybody can find a non-private entry point for this same data please post it in an answer. Thanks.**

Kudos to [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) for facilitating this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static EmailTraceListenerData GetEmailLogConfiguration()
{
    var rootWebConfig1 = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");
    var section = rootWebConfig1.GetSection("loggingConfiguration");
    var loggingSection = section as Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings;

    if (loggingSection != null) {
        // Reference to Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.dll and
        // Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll required for the code below
        foreach (Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.TraceListenerData listener in loggingSection.TraceListeners) {
            var emailTraceListenerData = listener as EmailTraceListenerData;
            if (emailTraceListenerData != null) {
                // Can obtain FromAddress, ToAddress, SmtpServer and SmtpPort 
                // as property of  emailTraceListenerData;
                return emailTraceListenerData;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Web.config file is as follow:

[image: web.config file]

For Windows application, you can open the .config file with`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration`instead of WebConfigurationManager.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem very verbose, here is my solution:

```
    public static TraceListenerData GetTraceListener(string name)
    {
        var log = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("loggingConfiguration") as LoggingSettings;

        return log.TraceListeners.Single(tl => tl.Name == name);
    }
```

Once you've called this helper method you can cast the result to whatever type the listener is such as RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, EmailTraceListenerData, FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, FormattedDatabaseTraceListenerData