# using `mailSettings` section of App.Config with Enterprise Library 5 Logging Block

Tags: logging, enterprise-library, app-config

I'm trying to set up some console applications to use the Enterprise Library 5 Logging Block.

I've defined the necessary elements in my app.config file and I know they work because the Event Log trace listener is working correctly.  The issue is with my email trace listeners.  Essentially I'd rather it make use of the `configuration\system.net\mailSettings\smtp` configuration section rather than individually configuring the multiple email listeners (also so I can have the DEBUG version "sending" emails to a local directory rather than an actual email).  My configuration looks something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>
  <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Email Trace Listener"
           type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.EmailTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.EmailTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           toAddress="some@address"
           fromAddress="some@address"
           subjectLineStarter="APPLICATION -- "
           subjectLineEnder=" -- Release"
           filter="Information"
           formatter="Text Formatter" />
      <add name="Informational Email"
           type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.EmailTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.EmailTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           toAddress="some@address"
           fromAddress="some@address"
           subjectLineStarter="APPLICATION -- "
           subjectLineEnder=" -- Release"
           formatter="Minimalist Text Formatter" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}"
           name="Text Formatter" />
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}"
           name="Minimalist Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Event Log Listener" />
          <add name="Email Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
      <add switchValue="Information" name="Email">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Informational Email" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Event Log Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </notProcessed>
      <errors switchValue="Error" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Email Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="valid.local.SMTP.server"/>
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Temp"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

When I change `deliveryMethod="Network"` to `deliveryMethod=SpecifiedPickupDirectory` all the emails are written out to the configured directory as expected.  But when it's set to Network no emails are sent out.

I verified with a web application that we have set up nearly identically that it works with the Network configuration just fine.  I'm not seeing any additional event log messages about not being able to send emails (either it really isn't being logged, or it's being swallowed...).  I'm at a loss for the next steps to get this working.  Has anybody else ran into this issue?

Comment: You maybe can use **programmatically** like ***http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485438/programmatically-access-enterprise-library-logging-configuration-object-model*** and ***http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361077/log-messages-going-to-previously-created-log-file***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue.  Apparently if you want it to use the SMTP host configured in `configuration\system.net\mailSettings\smtp` you still need to specify a blank string for the smtpServer attribute of the trace listener.  So instead of this:

```
<add name="Email Trace Listener"
     type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.EmailTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
     listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.EmailTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
     toAddress="some@address"
     fromAddress="some@address"
     subjectLineStarter="APPLICATION -- "
     subjectLineEnder=" -- Release"
     filter="Information"
     formatter="Text Formatter" />
```

You need to use this:

```
<add name="Email Trace Listener"
     type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.EmailTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
     listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.EmailTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
     toAddress="some@address"
     fromAddress="some@address"
     subjectLineStarter="APPLICATION -- "
     subjectLineEnder=" -- Release"
     filter="Information"
     smtpServer=""
     formatter="Text Formatter" />
```

Apparently leaving the attribute off doesn't mean it will pass a null string for the host to the SmtpClient like I initially thought.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that this approach does not work any more in Enterprise Library 6, creating a LogWriter throws an exception if the `smtpServer`'s value is an empty string. Does anybody know a solution for this in version 6?