# Enterprise Library 6 - dynamically change log file name

Tags: c#, logging, web-config, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-6

Is it possible to dynamically set log folder and file name in C# which overrides the config value(file name) in the Listeners section of logging configuration? 
Tried to follow the below link but it is applicable only for EL 5
[Log messages going to previously created log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361077/log-messages-going-to-previously-created-log-file)

This is how i Initialize EL Logging:

```
 IConfigurationSource configurationSource = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();
        LogWriterFactory logWriterFactory = new LogWriterFactory(configurationSource);
        Logger.SetLogWriter(logWriterFactory.Create(), false);

        ExceptionPolicyFactory factory = new ExceptionPolicyFactory(configurationSource);
        ExceptionPolicy.SetExceptionManager(factory.CreateManager());
```

These are my web.config entries inside the listeners tag:

```
 <add name="RollingFlatFileTraceLog" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    fileName="C:\logs\Trace.log" footer=""
    formatter="CustomRollingFlatFileLogFormatter"
    header="" rollFileExistsBehavior="Overwrite" rollInterval="Day"
    rollSizeKB="2048" maxArchivedFiles="52" />
  <add name="RollingFlatFileErrorLog" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    fileName="C:\logs\Error.log" footer="----------------------------------------"
    formatter=" CustomRollingFlatFileLogFormatter "
    header="----------------------------------------" rollFileExistsBehavior="Overwrite"
    rollInterval="Day" rollSizeKB="2048" maxArchivedFiles="52" />
```

I use Logger.Write and ExceptionPolicy.HandleException to write to the corresponding trace and error logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best (and easiest!) approach would be to use programmatic configuration to set the filename.

However, you can use a similar approach to modify settings at runtime.  Setup the configuration in an external file and use a file configuration source in app/web.config.  An external file is necessary to avoid a configuration is read-only exception.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    </configSections>
    <enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource selectedSource="File-based Configuration Source">
        <sources>
            <add name="File-based Configuration Source" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                filePath="entlib.config" />
        </sources>
    </enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

And configure the external file (entlib.config in this case):

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
        <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    </configSections>
    <exceptionHandling>
        <exceptionPolicies>
            <add name="Policy">
                <exceptionTypes>
                    <add name="All Exceptions" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                        postHandlingAction="NotifyRethrow">
                        <exceptionHandlers>
                            <add name="Logging Exception Handler" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                                logCategory="General" eventId="100" severity="Error" title="Enterprise Library Exception Handling"
                                formatterType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.TextExceptionFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling"
                                priority="0" />
                        </exceptionHandlers>
                    </add>
                </exceptionTypes>
            </add>
        </exceptionPolicies>
    </exceptionHandling>
    <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
        <listeners>
            <add name="Event Log Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Text Formatter"
                log="" machineName="." traceOutputOptions="None" />
            <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                fileName="trace.log" />
        </listeners>
        <formatters>
            <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}"
                name="Text Formatter" />
        </formatters>
        <categorySources>
            <add switchValue="All" name="General">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="Flat File Trace Listener" />
                </listeners>
            </add>
        </categorySources>
        <specialSources>
            <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
            <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
            <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="Event Log Listener" />
                </listeners>
            </errors>
        </specialSources>
    </loggingConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

Use the `SerializableConfigurationSource` from the blog posting:

```
public class SerializableConfigurationSource : IConfigurationSource
{
    Dictionary<string, ConfigurationSection> sections = new Dictionary<string, ConfigurationSection>();

    public SerializableConfigurationSource()
    {
    }

    public ConfigurationSection GetSection(string sectionName)
    {
        ConfigurationSection configSection;

        if (sections.TryGetValue(sectionName, out configSection))
        {
            SerializableConfigurationSection section = configSection as SerializableConfigurationSection;

            if (section != null)
            {
                using (StringWriter xml = new StringWriter())
                using (XmlWriter xmlwriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(xml))
                {
                    section.WriteXml(xmlwriter);
                    xmlwriter.Flush();

                    MethodInfo methodInfo = section.GetType().GetMethod("DeserializeSection", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    methodInfo.Invoke(section, new object[] { XDocument.Parse(xml.ToString()).CreateReader() });

                    return configSection;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void Add(string sectionName, ConfigurationSection configurationSection)
    {
        sections[sectionName] = configurationSection;
    }

    public void AddSectionChangeHandler(string sectionName, ConfigurationChangedEventHandler handler)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Remove(string sectionName)
    {
        sections.Remove(sectionName);
    }

    public void RemoveSectionChangeHandler(string sectionName, ConfigurationChangedEventHandler handler)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public event EventHandler<ConfigurationSourceChangedEventArgs> SourceChanged;

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

Bootstrap the blocks at startup:

```
IConfigurationSource configSource = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();

var loggingSettings = configSource.GetSection(LoggingSettings.SectionName) as LoggingSettings;    
var data = loggingSettings.TraceListeners.First(t => t.Name == "Flat File Trace Listener") as FlatFileTraceListenerData;
// Change the file name
data.FileName = "trace_1.txt";

var loggingXmlConfigSource = new SerializableConfigurationSource();
loggingXmlConfigSource.Add(LoggingSettings.SectionName, loggingSettings);

var logFactory = new LogWriterFactory(loggingXmlConfigSource);
Logger.SetLogWriter(logFactory.Create());

IConfigurationSource config = ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create();
ExceptionPolicyFactory factory = new ExceptionPolicyFactory(config);

ExceptionManager exManager = factory.CreateManager();
ExceptionPolicy.SetExceptionManager(exManager);

// This will log to the file trace_1.txt
ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(new Exception(), "Policy");
```

Comment: Thanks Randy, Changed to RollingFlatFileListenerData , was able to use your solution ,the log file name is set in memory dynamically during the startup and is working as expected!! Thanks again. Since my solution is running in a windows service(that runs without any restarts), in order to refresh the memory, guess i have to restart the service at midnight for the logging to re-initialize(My requirement is to place the log file in a directory having today's name YYYYMMDD - 12.AM).

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in the post, Setup the configuration in an external file. External file means, can you confirm in which path we have to place the Entlib.config file.

Comment: Something like this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300063/can-i-create-config-file-and-include-it-to-web-config